# Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement. Cannot return after useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

After fetching data from json, I want to return the array to use in other components. But I got the error "Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement." and I don't know what this error means. How can I fix that?

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Products = () => {
  const[products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://camera-store-60351-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/Products.json');
      const responseData = await response.json();

      const loadProducts = [];
      console.log(responseData);
      for (const key in responseData) {
        loadProducts.push({
          id: key,
          title: responseData[key].title,
          category: responseData[key].category,
          img: responseData[key].img,
          price: responseData[key].price,
        });
      }
      setProducts(loadProducts);
    };

    fetchProducts();
  }, []);
    
  return products;
}

export default Products;
```

The code I use `Products`:

```
import Content from "./Content"
import Products from "../store/Products"
import { useState } from "react"

const Main = () => {
  const[data, setState] = useState(Products);

  return (
    <div className="row  my-4 mx-2">
      <Content array={data} />
    </div>    
  )
};

export default Main
```

Content components:

```
import Card from "../UI/Card";

const Content = props => {
  const data = props.array;
  return (
    <div className="col">
      <div className="row">
        {data.map((values) => (
          <Card 
            key={values.id} 
            title={values.title} 
            image={values.img} 
            price={values.price} 
            id={values.id}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Content
```

I can render a component using products as props right in this but cannot return the products alone.

Comment: You should rename `Products` to `useProducts`, and your error is in code you're not showing us, where you call `Products`

Comment: Is `Products` a React component? What is it returning to be rendered? How is `Products` rendered? Is `Products` supposed to be a React hook? Please [edit] to provide all relevant code you are working with. See [mcve].

Comment: I edited my question below, could you please take a look again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are trying to use `Products` as a [lazy initialization function](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state), and the "hook" is only called on the initial render. I've emphasized the relevant details from the docs.

> The `initialState` argument is the state used during the initial render.
> In subsequent renders, it is disregarded. If the initial state is the
> result of an expensive computation, you may ***provide a function***
> instead, which ***will be executed only on the initial render.***

The `useState` and `useEffect` hooks in `Products` are not always called.

Update `Products` to be named `useProducts` so it's a correctly named custom React hook, and call the hook in the `Main` component directly.

Example:

```js
const useProducts = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://camera-store-60351-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/Products.json');
      const responseData = await response.json();

      const loadProducts = [];

      for (const key in responseData) {
        loadProducts.push({
          id: key,
          title: responseData[key].title,
          category: responseData[key].category,
          img: responseData[key].img,
          price: responseData[key].price,
        });
      }

      setProducts(loadProducts);
    };

    fetchProducts();
  }, []);
    
  return products;
}
```

```
const Main = () => {
  const products = useProducts();

  return (
    <div className="row  my-4 mx-2">
      <Content array={products} />       
    </div>    
  );
};
```

Comment: So I can't use `useState` with `useProduct()`? Because I want to change the products's state later by using filtering in my app.

Comment: @Onanigod You can, and are, using a `useState` hook in the `useProducts` hook. Are you saying you want to later be able to update the `products` state in `useProducts`? You can return also the `setProducts` state updater function from `useProducts`. Keep in mind though that React hooks don't share state, each "instance" of `useProducts` would have its own state. If you need to use this hook in more than one place and access the ***same*** state, then creating a React Context would be more ideal, then the custom `useProducts` hook just returns the common context value.

Comment: @Onanigod That said, if what you want to really do is just filter the `products` state, this is what is commonly referred to as derived state, in that the filtered data is ***derived*** from the `products` array source of truth and *some* filtering conditions. Either filter the data in-line prior to mapping it to JSX, or use the `useMemo` hook to compute and memoize the filtered result. Hopefully this all makes sense.